# PD1 certification query

Tags: certification

Am planning for PD1 certifcation. But dont have any study material. Also i am unaware of lightning in salesforce. Can anyone give pointers to good online courses to crack PD1 exam in one go.

Thanks,
Sheshadri

Comment: [https://trailhead.salesforce.com](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/)

Answer (score 3):

The [Salesforce Certification](http://certification.salesforce.com/platformdeveloperI) website for Platform Developer I provides a detailed, subject-by-subject exam outline. The best way to pass the exam is to research and thoroughly understand exactly the material that Salesforce tells you is on the test. All of it is documented in Trailhead and in the documentation library at developer.salesforce.com.